# React State returning Undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am having a state called `mediaRecorder` which is empty initially. After a particular process this state is updated to a new value. But when the value of this state is called in the `useEffect` it is returning the initial empty value:

```
  const [mediaRecorder, setMediaRecorder] = useState();

  ...
  const func = () => {
   setMediaRecorder(newVal); //updating the value
  }

  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("serveVideo", (_) =>    //this is called after the 'func' function
       mediaRecorder.stop();  // undefined or empty
    );

    return () => {
      socket.off("vidBlob");
    };
  }, [mediaRecorder]);
```

Comment: `mediaRecorder` in the callback function on the socket has the value of the initial state. You could add `mediaRecorder` to the dependency array to update the value accordingly

Comment: @RubenSmn Thanks! But I already did try that. Still it is undefined. Updated the code also

Comment: You claim that the callback function provided to `socket.on("serveVideo")` is called after `func`. Looking at your code, this hypothesis is certainly wrong. Can you edit your code to show where `func` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `UseEffect()` runs asynchronously

i.e If code order is

```
someFunction()
...
...
useEffect((){},[mediaRecorder]);
```

It doesn't mean that `useEffect` is executed after `someFunction`. Infact `useEffect` is executed based on the dependency array which is `mediaRecorder` in this case.

`UseEffect()` first runs when `mediaRecorder` is `null` i.e `initially`, it next runs only when the `mediaRecorder` changes irrespective of where it lies in the code segment.

As the first time `mediaRecorder` will be `null`, try to `check` if it's `not null`, only then perform operation

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(mediaRecorder!=null){                  // Try to wrap inside this if statement
   socket.on("serveVideo", (_) =>  mediaRecorder.stop(););
 }
  return () => {
    socket.off("vidBlob");
  };
}, [mediaRecorder]);
```

Comment: Do you understand why it works, though? You were claiming your event handler were called after `func`, which might indicate a misunderstanding in how React works

Comment: I have added the explanation please find the same in the post

Comment: Great. I was asking Ajit, but it's good you edited your post with the reason why the condition was necessary :)